# How to connect to another different database in PostgreSQL with ORM in Odoo?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, orm, odoo

I have a database in PostgreSQL, and I want to use it through Odoo ORM and then implement RPC stuff. I don't know how to connect to another database (in PostgreSQL).
I've googled for this and I have not found clairvoyant solutions or information. Can someone tell me about this? what steps should I follow?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following code to create a new cursor and use the environment created with that cursor.

```
from openerp.modules.registry import RegistryManager
from openerp import api

registry = RegistryManager.get('new_database')
cr = registry.cursor()
env = api.Environment(cr, self.env.uid, {})
env['res.users'].search([])                     # you can run ORM methods here with the new environment
```

You can use this methods as well to manage the cursor and environment

```
env.reset()         # reset environment
env.cr              # pointer to the cr cursor
cr.rollback()       # rollback
cr.execute(         # execute any SQL query
    "UPDATE res_users SET password='new_password' WHERE id=1"
)
cr.commit()         # commit cr changes
cr.close()          # close cursor
```

The postgres role must have the right priviledges on both databases (the current database and the additional one).

**Note**: I couldn't update the real database with the `env` variable and ORM methods, but it can be used for reading purposes

Also tou can create a cursor like this:

```
with openerp.sql_db.db_connect('postgres').cursor() as cr2:
    cr2.execute('SELEC ...')
```